# jquery toggle class on parent item if any child element of class is clicked?

Tags: jquery

I have a menu with the following html.

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="foo">
        <div class="secondary" >
            <a href="/#">link</a>
            <div class="bar" >
                <div class="foo">
                    <a href="/#">link</a>
                </div>
                <div class="foo">
                    <a href="/#">link</a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

I have 2 different a element structures

```
.foo .secondary a 
.foo .secondary .bar .foo a
```

When `a` is clicked, I want to add a class to the foo which is the parent of .secondary, when any other of the 'a's are clicked I want to remove that class from the foo which is the parent of .secondary

something similar to

```
$( ".foo > a" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).closest(".secondary").closest(".foo").toggleclass("class");
});
```

How can I acheive this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your description is a bit confusing however if I understand correctly you want to remove the class from any previous elements that were selected.

Something like this should help

```
$( ".foo > a" ).click(function() {
   // toggle the current foo
   const $fooParent = $(this).closest('.foo').toggleClass("active-class")
  // remove from any other foo
  $('.foo').not($fooParent).removeClass('active-class')
});
```